# Call init inside of an array struct

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

In the old version of the data that I got from Json, `Pause` data was not in an array, so I used this line of code to do the unit testing:

```
let pause = Pause(attached: [PauseModel(range: 40 ..< 305)])
```

Then

```
let data = Data(pause: pause)
try lits.process(data: data)
```

The `pause` in `let data = Data(pause: pause)` is type of `Pause` struct (its struct is copied below). But I divided to `Pause`structs to two structs (First one can be considered as a root (under the named of `Pause`):

```
public struct Pause: Decodable {

   public let pause: [PauseData]

   private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case lists
      case pause
   }

   public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let series = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self).nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .lists)
      breaks = try series.decode([pauseData].self, forKey: .pause)
   }
}
```

As you can see `PauseData` is inside an array.

```
public struct PauseData: Decodable {

   public let attached: [PauseModel]

   init(attached: [PauseModel] = []) {
      self.attached = attached
   }

   private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case attached = "attached"
   }
}
```

So I need to write this line again:

```
let pause = Pause(attached: [PauseModel(range: 40 ..< 305)])
```

I can simply do it like that:

```
let pause = PauseData(attached: [PauseModel(range: 40 ..< 305)])
```

but the `let pause` should be a type of `Pause` struct. So Somehow I need re-write this line to be the type of `Pause` struct and also I can call the init  `init(attached: [PauseModel] = [])`. I can be appreciated if anyone can help me on that.

Thank you so much

Comment: Hey Pual, welcome to the site. Could you please clarify your question? I've read it carefully several times, and I still don't know what you're asking

Comment: Dear @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, thank you so much and sorry if my question wasn't clear. I updated it. I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a `Pause` contains an array of `PauseData`, each of which contain arrays of `PauseModel`, did I get that write? In that case, I think you're looking for just

```
let pause = Pause(attached: [
    PauseData(attached: [PauseModel(range: 40 ..< 305)])
])
```

But the naming of these structs is really confusing. Their names are different without a distinction.

The issue now is that there's no `Pause.init(attached:)` initializer. Typically the compiler will synthesize one for you, called the "member-wise initializer". The issue is that you specified your own initializer (`init(from decoder: Decoder) throws`), so the compiler is no longer synthesizing the member-wise initializer for you. There's two ways to address this.

1. You can implement the initializer yourself, as you already did with `PauseData`:

   ```
   init(attached: [PauseModel] = []) {
       self.attached = attached
   }
   ```
2. You can move your `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` implementation to an extension, so that the compiler can synthesize the memberwise initializer for you:

   ```
   public struct Pause {
      public let pause: [PauseData]
   }

   extension Pause: Decodable {
      private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case lists
         case pause
      }

      public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
         let series = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self).nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .lists)
         breaks = try series.decode([pauseData].self, forKey: .pause)
         self.init(pause: breaks)
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you much, I will change their name. But there is a problem here, `Pause ` doesn't have any initializer that let me to use  `let pause = Pause(attached: [ `

Comment: Ah, you should have mentioned that in your questino :p I'll update my answer.

Comment: Happy new year to you too! Yeah definitely clean up the names here. A `Pause` has a `pause` (that doesn't really make sense, it's already supposed to be a pause!), which has type `[PauseData]` (that's multiple pause datas, but `pause` is a singular word!) Each `PauseData` has an `attached` (wrong form, variable names should be nouns or noun phrases, so it should be `attachment` or `attachments`), and we don't really know what it is from the name, it's just an attached... something. It happens to be an array (even though the name is singular again!)

Comment: This is a lot of violations of [the principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

Comment: Thank you so much for your advices. I have changed the names based of what you said.